# word that describes advantages being "surpassed" or "exceeded" by disadvantages

Tags: word-request

For instance, a sports car might have all the technology and power but the high cost is its disadvantage compared to an average car. So "However, the advantage of high technology and power is **_____ed** by the high cost."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term **'outweigh'** - to exceed in weight, value, or importance - is generally used when the advantages make the disadvantages seem less important.

In a situation such as this, where the disadvantages make the advantages seem less important, the term **'overshadow'** is a more suitable turn of phrase.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overshadow

> However, the advantage of high technology and power is overshadowed by
>   the high cost.

Answer (score 2):

How about "eclipsed"?

> **Eclipse** (v): 1.1. Deprive (someone or something) of significance or power.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eclipse)]